# SQL Server database not executing query due to space error

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server management studio to maintain a database, But when i am executing any query its giving me space error, Actually my disk was not having enough space so I shrink-ed the .ldf file to get some free space, After shrinking .ldf file i got some free space, I thought now my database will work but problem is still there, Still i am getting the same error while executing even a simple query. For Example

```
Select top (10) from table
```

what else i can do to run my database properly

Comment: Copy paste the error message you are getting.

Comment: If you don't have enough free disk space, you need to either move your database to a larger drive, or clean up unused files on your existing drive. SQL Server needs a lot of scratch disk space to use for the log file especially. Use "Disk Cleanup" to start, or something like "space sniffer" (free utility) to locate where you disk space is being used up. Or get a bigger disk and move your database to it.

Comment: I am having only one database in that drive

Comment: Are you sure it;s not telling you that the tempdb is full and can't be expanded?  You may only have on user database but SQL server also maintains it;s own system databases, that need space on disk and in their files.

Look also at the expansion setting for the databases. By default SQL server sets it at 10%, which would mean for a large DB it would try to claim a lot more disk space than it actually needs when it expands - e.g a 10GB database will try to expand by another 1GB, a 100GB database would try for another 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

The ldf is your log file.  Shrinking a log file to gain space is like exhaling to make yourself look thinner.  As soon as you breath again, you're back to your bloated size. :)

If shrinking the ldf helped temporarily, you need to add more space to your server and move the log file to its own drive.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following:

- **initial size for log files** in your database -> Properties -> Files. You cannot shrink to a lower value
- **recovery model in your database** -> Properties -> Options -> Recovery model. If it is *Full*, than you cannot shrink the log too much. However, if you managed to shrink it, it is most probably *Simple*.

If you are using Windows Server, [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/05/13/how-to-clean-up-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-new-update/) might help you in getting some space through disk cleanup and/or WinSxS cleanup (works mainly for OS partition).

Also, [NTFS compression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976811.aspx) might quickly reduce used space for files like temporary files, various log files etc. (do not apply this for SQL Server folders/subfolders).